# Proof of the divergence of a monotonically increasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Say that the limit of sequence $(A_n)$ as $n \to \infty$ equals $+\infty$ if for every $r \in \mathbb R$, there is an integer $N$ such that $(A_n) > R$ for all $n \geq N$.

> Show that a divergent monotone increasing sequence converges to $+\infty$ in this sense.

I am having trouble understanding how to incorporate in my proof the fact that the sequence is monotonically increasing.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*What is required for a monotone increasing sequence to converge*?

- See [Monotone Convergence Theorem for Sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).$(*)$

By$\; (*):\;$ Since $A_n$ is a monotone increasing sequence, if $A_n$ were bounded above, then it would *converge* to some value $L < +\infty$. But we are given $A_n$ is a *divergent* monotone increasing sequence. Hence $A_n$ cannot be bounded above; i.e., $A_n$ *has no upper bound*. (That's simply applying the *contrapositive* of the monotone convergence theorem).

That is, there is no $M > 0$ such that $(A_n)$ is bounded above by $M$. This means
$$\forall M>0,\; \exists N\in \mathbb{N}:A_N>M.$$

And since we are given that $(A_n)$ is monotone increasing, $n\ge N\implies A_n>A_N>M$.

This holds for $M'<M$ too, so
$$\forall M>0,\;\;\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:\ n\ge N\implies A_n>M$$
and hence, $A_n\to +\infty$.

Comment: Why $\exists M$ and not $\forall M$? I'd have bet it should've been $\forall M$ but since you are two to use $\exists M$, there must be something I missed...

Comment: I still don't get it... "has no upper bound" $\equiv$ $\lnot$("has upper bound")$\equiv \lnot(\exists M, \forall N, A_N < M) \equiv \forall M \lnot(\forall N, A_N < M)\equiv \forall M ,\exists N, \lnot(A_N<M)\equiv \forall M ,\exists N, A_N\ge M$

Comment: i clicked it twice, my bad, forgive my noobness

Comment: it was so right, i clicked it twice hahahaha

Answer (score 1):

If $(a_n)$ is bounded above then by the Monotone Convergence theorem, $(a_n)$ converges which is a contradiction. Thus $(a_n)$ is not bounded above by some $M>0$, that is
$$\exists M>0\ \exists N\in \mathbb{N}:a_N>M$$
But as $(a_n)$ is increasing, 
$$n\ge N\implies a_n>a_N>M$$
This holds for $M'<M$ as well and so
$$\forall R>0\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:\ n\ge N\implies a_n>R$$
and so $a_n\to +\infty$.

Note that we only incorporate divergence to show un-boundedness. This is done by the [Monotone Convergence Theorem for sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem)